# Enabling compiz effects on Gnome3

Tags: 11.10, compiz, gnome, effects

How can I enable `compiz` effects on `Gnome3` on `ubuntu 11.10`?

I already installed `ccsm` and `compiz-plugins-extra`.

What else should I do?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! By "GNOME 3", are you referring to the GNOME Shell interface or GNOME Classic? You can't use Compiz in GNOME Shell, but you can in Classic.

Comment: Related (but *not* a duplicate): http://askubuntu.com/q/8276/18612

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm sorry for bad news but Gnome3 will not work with Compiz as it has its own windows manager compositor called Mutter/Clutter.
However, if you will use Gnome 2 you will be able to run Compiz and enjoy its effects.

Comment: Technically, GNOME Classic is GNOME 3, as is GNOME Shell. We must be careful with terminology here.

Comment: Mutter and compiz are both compositing window managers that make use of 3d acceleration.  Gnome 3's shell relies on mutter in the same was as Unity3d relies on compiz: you cannot switch window managers unless you also stop using gnome-shell.  On the other hand, mutter does a lot of the same things that compiz does and does provide *some* similar effects, though without any of the same emphasis on customisability - customising it is extremely limited if possible at all - for the most part you are stuck with it as it is.  It's designed more to just work and not make itself obvious.