# Can I use Compiz with GNOME Shell?

Tags: 12.04, compiz, gnome

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Compiz-like effects in Gnome shell?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8276/compiz-like-effects-in-gnome-shell)

Can I use Compiz with GNOME Shell in Ubuntu 12.04? If I can, how?

I must use `compiz --replace` to start Compiz, but then the top panel and Activities disappears.